# How to fix " Error 263 for command: close <mp3 file>" error related to Playsound in Python

Tags: python, python-playsound

I was trying to code a voice assistant with the help of an online tutorial. When I tried to run the code, I kept kept getting an error message saying:

```
Error 263 for command:
        close voice.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: voice.mp3
```

***Note**: "voice.mp3" is the name I gave to the mp3 file.

This is the only function in the program which used "voice.mp3", as well as the Playsound module:

```
def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, tld="ca", lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)
```

I believe it has something to do with Playsound.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you forget to show your code?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826091/the-specified-device-is-not-open-or-is-not-recognized-by-mci , may can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826091/the-specified-device-is-not-open-or-is-not-recognized-by-mci)

Comment: @abdou_dev If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of just posting a link...

Answer (score 1):

I just added `./` to the name of the file in the code.

```
filename = "./voice.mp3"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works. But it's a strange behavior and should be documented.