# python playsound "The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I included a sound file in the same folder as my jupyter notebook file and the file cant be read

```
from playsound import playsound
file = "SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"
playsound(file)
```

It then gave me this error message

```
PlaysoundException: 
Error 263 for command:
        open SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

Comment: some answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826091/the-specified-device-is-not-open-or-is-not-recognized-by-mci) .   
IPython can also play mp3 files with Audio