# Can't invoke "bind" command - Drummer can't drum : (

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am extremely new to coding, and I'm trying to make an interactive drum set.
I want to make it so where when you press a certain key, that drum sound plays and changes the background image to that drum being played.

[Code I wrote for the snare drum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7gGz.png)

[Epic drummer drumming epicly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTXW9.png)

The idea is that when "s" is pressed, the background image will change to the dude hitting the snare drum, a sound clip of a snare drum will play, then after a very brief amount of time the background image returns to the original.

When executed, the initial background image is displayed, but nothing else happens and this error is displayed: "tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed"

Since I am very new to coding (and my teacher does not posses the capabilities to help me), I have no idea what I could even try to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Don't share images of code, add the code in your question directly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

I got the keypress and background image change to work with this code:

```
import turtle
from playsound import playsound

wn = turtle.Screen()
Base = "Background.png"
wn.bgpic(Base)

def SNARE():
    wn.bgpic("Snare Hit.png")
    wn.update()
    playsound("Snare-Drum-Hit.mp3")
    wn.bgpic(Base)
    wn.update()

wn.onkeypress(SNARE, "s")

turtle.listen()

wn.mainloop()
```

With Python 3.9.9 and playsound 1.2.2. The current playsound version does not work for me. For installing version 1.2.2 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826091/the-specified-device-is-not-open-or-is-not-recognized-by-mci).

Unfortunately, playsound starts the sound with a significant delay. This doesn't give you a real drummer experience ;)

But in principle it works.